# How do i get numberOfRowsInSection from nested NSMutableDictionary?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to follow this post http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-index-list-uitableview/ to create sections using `UITableViewController`.

I am using two `NSMutableDictionaries` first(`_curatedItemDictionary`) dictionary is to store key value pairs from Parse and second (`_sectionsDictionary`) is to store these in dictionary as key and values as Category type.

```
 [_sectionsDictionary setObject:[obj objectForKey:@"Category"] forKey:_curatedItemDictionary];
```

I did this because i couldn't store the key as category and value as dictionary as dictionaries will not support duplicate keys.

I am getting `numberOfSectionsInTableView` by using the below code

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    for(NSString *key in [_sectionsDictionary allKeys]) {
        [_cleanArray addObject:[_sectionsDictionary objectForKey:key]];
    }
    NSCountedSet *set = [[NSCountedSet alloc] initWithArray:_cleanArray];        
    for (id item in set) {           
        NSInteger count =  (unsigned long)[set countForObject:item];
        [_rowForIndexArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:count]];
    }        
    _cleanSectionArray = [[NSSet setWithArray:_cleanArray] allObjects];
    return [_cleanSectionArray count];
}
```

How do i get `numberOfRowsInSection` from the above information ? How do i know which items are being iterated for a particular section ?

Here is the code I am using to create `curatedItemDictionary` from Parse.com data

```
PFQuery *query  = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:[NSString stringWithString:self.classname]];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            // The find succeeded.

            for (PFObject *obj in objects) {

             self.curatedItemDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];


             [_curatedItemDictionary setValue:[obj objectForKey:@"ItemName"] forKey:@"ItemName"];
            [_curatedItemDictionary setValue:[obj objectForKey:@"Price"] forKey:@"Price"];


            [_sectionsDictionary setObject:[obj objectForKey:@"Category"] forKey:_curatedItemDictionary];


              [self.tableView reloadData];
        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
    }];
```

Comment: UITableViews don't work particularly well with dictionaries - you really need to use arrays.  You don't provide the details of your Parse data structure so I can't give you an answer in code, but I would create an array of category strings and a dictionary where the keys are the category strings and the values are an array of item strings.  Then your section headings are given by the contents of the categories array and the number of rows in section is itemsDictionaries[categories[indexPath.section]].count

Comment: Hi Paulw11 thanks for your answer. I couldn't understand your array of category strings concept. Could you please give me a pseudocode based on my parse code below http://pastebin.com/kwNe0Bei

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code provided in the comment to the original post something similar to that, just an alternative:

```
self.sectionsDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary new];
NSMutableArray *sectionsArray;

for (PFObject *obj in objects) {
    sectionsArray = [self.sectionsDictionary objectForKey: [obj objectForKey:@"Category"]];
    if (nil == sectionsArray) sectionsArray = [NSMutableArray new];
    [sectionsArray addObject: obj]
    [self.sectionsDictionary setObject: sectionsArray forKey: [obj objectForKey:@"Category"]];
}
```

Then in your `numberOfSectionsInTableView` you can get the amount of sections just by accessing `count` method on `NSMutableDictionary`

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
     return [self.sectionsDictionary count];
}
```

And then if you need number of rows in each particular section:

```
- (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView*)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSArray *keys = [self.sectionsDictionary allKeys];
    id aKey = [keys objectAtIndex:section];
    NSMutableArray *arr = [self.sectionsDictionary objectForKey:aKey];

    return (arr) ? arr.count : 0;
}
```

But of course you can loop through the keys in your sectionsDictionary when preparing the datasource and put section index with some key, so you do not need to do use the `allKeys` trick.

Comment: The problem is in this line  [self.sectionsDictionary setObject: sectionsArray forKey: [obj objectForKey:@"Category"]]; Keys cannot be duplicated. That was the whole reason why i am doing this [_sectionsDictionary setObject:[obj objectForKey:@"Category"] forKey:_curatedItemDictionary];

Comment: That won't duplicate the key.  It will either add a new value for that key or replace the value associated with that key

Comment: @teamnorge you could probably use the more 'modern' [key] and [index] syntax for accessing dictionaries and arrays

Comment: @Rider Forest. When I do not really follow what are you trying to do. If you are not categorising objects from `objects` array in sections by `[obj objectForKey:@"Category"] ` category, what is the criteria to put them in different sections?

Comment: Hi Paulw11. I have multiple Categories with the same names will this work for me ?

Comment: @Paulw1, you are right, I was just trying to "copy" the topic starter's coding style so its more understandable to him.

Comment: @RiderForest `sectionsDictionary` contains an array of objects for each category.  The keys of `sectionsDictionary` are the category names.  The code retrieves the `sectionsArray` associated with the category name.  If this is nil then a new array is created.  The object is then added to the array and the array is added to the dictionary.  The code could be optimised slightly by only associating the array with the key when it is created

Comment: Thanks Paulw11 i couldn't comprehend this line  sectionsArray = [self.sectionsDictionary objectForKey: [obj objectForKey:@"Category"]]; As this is trying to get something from sectionsDictionary before adding. Could you edit this ?

Comment: Nothing to edit - this tries to retrieve the array in the dictionary associated with the category - it will either return an array or nil.  If it returns nil then a new array is allocated

Comment: So far so good... i'm unable to populate the sectionsDictionary data inside my cellForRowAtIndexPath. Could you explain further on that ?

Comment: I did it. Thanks a lot Paulw11 and teamnorge thanks for the pseudocode.