# Unable to create number of sections in tableView based on no of items in dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

hello I have a dictionary like this

```
  {
        0 =     {
            ProductRequest =         {
                description = "";
                "destination_country" = "";
            };
            User =         {
                "first_name" = irfan;
                "last_name" = sheikhg;
            };
        };
        1 =     {
            ProductRequest =         {
                description = dummy;
                "destination_country" = dummy;
                "user_id" = 9;
            };
            User =         {
                "first_name" = john;
                "last_name" = Doe;
            };
        };
        code = 200;
    }
```

If I return the sections like this, my program crashes

```
return dict.count - 1
```

If I do this

```
return dict.count
```

Program doesn't crash but it returns one empty section extra. By looking at my array you will know that 3rd element I am sending success code in array, thats why I am doing `dict.count - 1`

**Complete Class Code**

```
  class RequestTableViewController: UITableViewController {
  var dict = NSDictionary()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    getRequestsFromServer()
  }

  override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return dict.count - 1
  }

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return 1
  }

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! RequestTableViewCell
    if(indexPath.section == 0) {
      cell.requestTitleTextView.text = (((self.dict["\(indexPath.row)"] as?NSDictionary)!["ProductRequest"] as?NSDictionary)!["request_title"] as?NSString)! as String

      let firstName = (((self.dict["\(indexPath.row)"] as?NSDictionary)!["User"] as?NSDictionary)!["first_name"] as?NSString)! as String
      let  lastName = (((self.dict["\(indexPath.row)"] as?NSDictionary)!["User"] as?NSDictionary)!["last_name"] as?NSString)! as String

      cell.userNameLabel.text = firstName.uppercaseString + " " +  lastName.uppercaseString
    }
    return cell
  }

  func getRequestsFromServer() {
    let url:String = Variables.GETALLREQUESTS_URI
    let params = ["data":"get"]
    ServerRequest.postToServer(url, params: params) { result, error in

      if let result = result {
        let code =  result["code"] as? Int
        print(result)
        if(code == 200) {
          self.dict = result
          dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            // DO SOMETHING ON THE MAINTHREAD
            self.tableView.reloadData()
          })

        } else if(code==500 ) {
          dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            AlertView().showAlert(Message.INTERNETISNOTCONNECTED)
            /*let alert = UIAlertView()
            alert.message = Message.INTERNETISNOTCONNECTED
            alert.addButtonWithTitle("Ok")
            alert.show()*/
          })
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Update:**

When It crashes. nothing is printing out on console. here is the image 
[image]

Comment: does it crash because it's initially empty? you really haven't given us any details so all we can do is guess...

Comment: 'my program crashes' isn't that useful ;) Can you add the stack trace / exceptions to the question so we can see where it's crashing please?

Comment: @Wain yes initially its empty

Comment: see this once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31419405/how-do-i-get-numberofrowsinsection-from-nested-nsmutabledictionary

Answer (score 0):

I think @Wain is onto something :)

If your dict is initially empty then you're returning `-1` as the number of sections - that probably won't work. You will need to check for that in your numberOfSections method :

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    guard dict.count > 0 else { return 0 }

    return dict.count - 1
}
```

Though a better way to deal with this might be to be smarter about how you calculate the number of sections; just subtracting 1 from the count is going to run into trouble if the server ever returns any other keys apart from 'code' . . .

Comment: dictionaries are also unordered so your table contents are going to be arbitrarily sorted => take the parts you need out of the dictionary and use an array instead, then you can reliably use the array count

Comment: @Wain - the code accesses the dictionary by converting the section number to a string `"\(indexPath.section)`" and using that as the key, so it would be in the correct order when it's rendered - I think the keys in the dictionary are just strings containing integers?. Though I absolutely agree an array would be the way to go!

Comment: @deanWombourne hello thanks for your help. Now the program doesn't crash but somehow the results doesn't come up on the table orderly. Its hard to explain but in short some data of first row result showing on the second one and on the second one username is not showing. its complex to explain. but in short if I use array will this problem be solved ?